# Fixing the Gtk-WARNING "Unable to locate theme engine" on CentOS 7 when using gvim

Tags: vim, gtk

On CentOS 7, this is the below warning when I open any file using `gvim`:

```
(gvim:48476): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:18.971: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "hcengine",
```

Comment: Do you still get the message if you run `gvim -u NONE file`? Did you install vim from a package manager or build it yourself?

Comment: Yes i am getting same message, I have installed it after changing the theme of terminal i am getting this message, i am using centOS7